# how to fix the Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a few tables, I wrote a sql to join those tables and insert the result to a final table. The final table is tb(account, date), account is a primary key. The problem came from the result of the query, which would look like following:

```
account     date
0001        09/01/2012
0001        09/02/2012
0002        09/01/2012
0003        09/03/2012
```

when I insert above those result records, I got Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error. How do I fix the query, I could get the result records like following

```
account     date
0001        09/02/2012 (get the latest date)
0002        09/01/2012
0003        09/03/2012
```

Thanks.

Comment: So if the final table only needs one row per account, why is `date` part of the primary key?

Comment: account is the primary key, date is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable (account, DATE)
SELECT account,
MAX(date)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY account
```

It would make a lot more sense if you were to show us the table schemas, original query, and soem example data.

Comment: Wow, someone is really playing with the arrows on your answer. I've seen it go from 1 to -1 to + 2 back to 1 again in the last minute.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Do I need add distinct in front of the account?

Comment: @GaolaiPeng no, you do not need to add `DISTINCT`. But note that if you run this query twice, you will get a PK violation, unless you change the `FROM` to pull completely different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to the query to prevent duplicates. If the final table already has some data prior to this population, you may also want to add a correlated `NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```
INSERT dbo.FinalTable(account, [date])
  SELECT account, [date] FROM 
  (
     SELECT account, MAX([date])
       FROM --... your join here
       GROUP BY account
  ) AS src (account, [date])
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1 
       FROM dbo.FinalTable 
       WHERE account = src.account
       AND [date]  = src.[date]
  );
```

Also consider using a more meaningful (and non-reserved) word for your `date` column(s).

*edit* sorry, missed the `(get the latest date)` bit.

Answer (score -1):

I think You need to `ORDER BY date DESC GROUP BY account` when you insert. However this alone will not work if you already have 0001 in table.

You'll need to insert non-existing records and then update existing ones (if that's what you want)